# Do extremely simple tables still require their own model class?

Tags: php, database, orm, laravel, eloquent

I've been using laravel (php mvc framework) for a few weeks now. Currently I am creating a model for every single non-pivot table. Even tables as simple as:

> #### id (unsigned int (PK)) | usertype (varchar(20))
>
> 1                              | guest
>
> 2                             | member
>
> 3                             | Moderator

Because it makes it easier to relate my other models to them using the eloquent ORM.

I was wondering if its normal to create models for such simple tables for the sake of utilizing an ORM or if there is a better approach?

Currently my application is functioning using models for these tables, but I still want to make sure I am picking up good coding conventions while I'm learning.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short answer: YES! If you have a pattern, stick to it...

Comment: And if you don't mind me asking for the long answer? :)

Comment: Actually, mirroring database tables in your domain logic is usually sign of poor design (you could call it - *design smell*). In your particular case, you actually need a well made `User` (or maybe `Account`) entity, which represents information from multiple tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here comes the long answer: YES!

I don't know when or why `model` became a synonym to `entity`, but this leads to confusion.

According to MVC inventor, Trygve Reenskaug, in the [original MVC article](http://pt.scribd.com/doc/6414921/Original-MVC-Pattern-Trygve-Reenskaug-1979):

> DEFINITION
>   A Model is an active representation of an abstraction in the form of data in a computing system

[...]

> The models are represented in the computer as acollection of data together with the methods necessary to process these data.

So, many people nowadays define (incorrectly) models as data representation, or the data storage or something else, but this is wrong.

Model deals with your application logic and this INCLUDES data abstraction, data storage, data processing, etc.

I use to call my data abstractions an `Entity` instead of `model`. My application model layer is called `Service` or `Application Model`. My storage layer is called just `Storage` and so on... All of this togheter is what we can call `Model`

That being clarified, now we can go on...

> ### You said:
>
> Because it makes it easier to relate my other models to them using the eloquent ORM.

That's enough!

Nothing keeps you away from using plan txt files as storage, but if your data relate to others, then you should look for a database.

Eloquent is an ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) and so, it relies on a database behind it. If you use txt files, how would do to recover users by their user type?

I'm not used to frameworks, but most of them generate entities automatically, you just need to declare them...

If some entity has no business logic and you just need to store it, so you don't need a "full model" for it. And that's what you're doing.

Hope I convinced you...

Comment: As pointed out (I think?) "Model" is a very loose name. Eloquent is an ORM, an implementation of the Active Record design pattern. The "Model", in that context, is both responsible for (A) querying the database **and** (B) representing an "entity" - a portion of your business logic. This can be contrasted with a more Domain Driven application design, in which you would separate your entity from the querying of your data source used to create/store a representation of an entity. Some advice: Chances are, using the ORM is the best way to go in your application.

Comment: Yes, data storage CAN BE parte of the model, but not always. Imagine a module that does only functional calculation over data. It has it's Model (logic), but no storage at all...